# error: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured

Tags: python, django

I installed Django and made a project called `joseph`. This is all I've done thus far. I can't access it at all, however, because I can only access the core commands. I get this message when I put it django-admin help:

> Note that only Django core commands are listed as settings are not properly configured (error: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.).

I have looked for an answer but all of the other ones seem to be about scenarios not like mine because they already have been able to do things. I haven't been at all. What am I supposed to do here?

Comment: It looks like *possibly* you are not running 'django-admin' from the right spot/in the right environment. That may not make sense to you at this point, however. Can you provide more details on what exactly you mean by "I can only access the core commands" and what exactly you typed in to the console, and in which directory you are in, what files it contains, etc? This would be very helpful.

Comment: I typed in 'django-admin help', and got that message I posted. I figured that those would be the only commands that would work, unless I defined the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable (have no idea what to put in it though). Typed in django-admin startproject joseph. It apparently is located in C:\Users\wasim\joseph, which is odd because I've looked in file explorer to no avail.

Comment: The PATH is C:\Users\wasim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Users\wasim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Heroku\bin. I don't know what else to say, because my file explorer won't show anything even after 10 minutes of loading.

Comment: "I installed Django and made a project called joseph" -- If creating the project worked at all, you should have a folder called `joseph`, which contains a file named `manage.py`, if I'm not mistaken. Unless it failed to create the project.